# How could I go about implementing pagination to my project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so I've recently completed a project that I was working on that displayed a list of pokemon, and once clicked on, the user is directed to the pokemon information page.

It looks as follows:

[image]

So I have my main dashboard.js that contains my "PokemonList"  as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import PokemonList from "../pokemon/PokemonList";

export default class Dashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col">
            <PokemonList />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

my PokemonList.js is responsible for obtaining the Pokemon information from the PokeAPI and the code is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PokemonCard from "./PokemonCard";
import axios from "axios";

export default class PokemonList extends Component {
  state = {
    url: "http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=600",
    pokemon: null
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const res = await axios.get(this.state.url);
    this.setState({ pokemon: res.data["results"] });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.state.pokemon ? (
          <div className="row">
            {this.state.pokemon.map(pokemon => (
              <PokemonCard
                key={pokemon.name}
                name={pokemon.name}
                url={pokemon.url}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        ) : (
          <h1>Loading Pokemon</h1>
        )}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

The pokemonList is built of several pokemonCards that's then displayed, but I don't think the coding for that is needed for what I'm looking for.

If I wanted to enable pagination, would I have to incorporate the code within my Dashboard.js or the pokemonList.js?

-----------------------EDIT--------------------------------------

[image]

Comment: Are you just asking how to implement pagination? What did you try?

Comment: Sorry but isn't this question more opinion based? You can implement pagination anyway you want, either handle it internally in `PokemonList` component or pass it as `prop` from `Dashboard` component. It depends on how you want to architecture your code and use case. If you're facing any difficulty in implementation then please add it to the question.

Comment: @DennisVash So pokeApi apparently has some form of pagination as mentioned on their documentation https://pokeapi.co/docs/v2.html , but when I change my url link to http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=20&offset=20 it simply limits it to 20, and no pagination links are made.

Comment: @vatz88 I tried downloading external react.js pagination libraries, but I was unsure as how to apply it to my currently existing project. Since they all just showed it from scratch with their own software.

Comment: Well according to the API, you can limit the `count` and call `next` when needed, so where is the problem? For example, you can show 20 on-page, and call `next` when user go to next one.

Comment: @DennisVash Oh, so would I need to manually create a next-page button? I thought it'd be similar to implementing something like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paginate

Comment: It depends on your architecture, you can also `GET` all pokemons, `chunk` them, and show accordingly on every page, it's your choice, thats why it's too broad.

Comment: @DennisVash Are there any guides you would recommend for pagination then? I guess I will have to read into this more. I've only ever used pagination with DataTables plugins which came a part of it, so I assumed it would be as simple as that.

Comment: It's simple, you just need to ask the right question, I made some simple pagination example once, you can check it here: https://github.com/denvash/react-pagination-example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199736/discussion-between-zadders-and-dennis-vash).

Comment: @DennisVash Based on the pagination function you have on github, after applying it etc. It works fine, but if there are 20 objects listed on the page, the cards shrink in size.

Comment: Well its css, nothing to do with it

Comment: @DennisVash I have edited the question and added a gif showing how the code directly affects it. not my CSS. Because If I keep my orginial code then it stays the right sizes.

Comment: Please learn about css, your component container might shrink them

Answer (score 1):

What you could use is this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-js-pagination

Then in your code the pagination would be smth like this:

```
    <Pagination
      activePage={this.state.activePage}
      itemsCountPerPage={this.state.itemsCountPerPage}
      totalItemsCount={this.state.pokemon.length}
      pageRangeDisplayed={5}
      onChange={::this.handlePageChange.bind(this)}
    />
```

handlePageChange function:

```
handlePageChange(pageNumber) {
    this.setState({activePage: pageNumber});
  }
```

then in the render function of your pokemonList.js:

```
let indexOfLastTodo = this.state.activePage * this.state.itemsCountPerPage;
let indexOfFirstTodo = indexOfLastTodo - this.state.itemsCountPerPage;
let renderedPokemons = this.state.pokemon.slice(indexOfFirstTodo, indexOfLastTodo);
```

and finally

```
{renderedPokemons.map(pokemon => (
              <PokemonCard
                key={pokemon.name}
                name={pokemon.name}
                url={pokemon.url}
              />
                ))}
```

Of course don't forget to include activePage and itemsCountPerPage in your state. I think I have done something like this in one of my earlier projects. Enjoy!

Comment: for the first chunk of code, is the <Pagination> elemented added to the PokemonList.js? similary for the handlepagechange and the final one.

Comment: yep, everything in the container PokemonList.js

Comment: I'm unsure where in my code to place the first two chunks of code you provided, I was able to make sense of the rest though

Comment: well you can place the Pagination under your row component , or anywhere else for that matter. the function you can place anywhere you like :)

Comment: For the pagination code, I seem to get an error on the line "onChange={::this.handlePageChange.bind(this)}
    />" 

The error occurs on the "::" symbol after onchange, and it says "Expression expected.ts(1109)" Is this something you're aware of?

Comment: The slice code isn't working actually, and when I did a console.log(this.state.pokemon); before the let renderedPokemons code, it returns me null. So for some reason your code has prevented the pokemon from loading in.

Comment: I narrowed it down to the error being within the renderedPokemons function.

Comment: Not sure why it returns null before the renderedPokemons code, might be cause you're using async/await and I was using window.fetch with promises. might help to wrap your return () in if(this.state.pokemon.length) to make sure pokemons are loaded before render

Comment: also try to test your code with fetch: window.fetch(this.state.url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((pokemon) => {
      this.setState({
         pokemon
      })